# Reduce function fails with three parameters and runs fine with two parameters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

```
from functools import reduce
o = [20,30,100,60,80,90]

#1 
print(reduce((lambda x,y:x+y),o)) # returns 380
#2
print(reduce((lambda x,y,z:x+y+z),o)) # FAILS
#3
print(reduce((lambda x,y,z=10:x+y+z),o)) # returns 430
```

Can someone explain why the #1 is working fine and #2 fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable [...]

This means that the function should accept 2 arguments, not 3. If you think of it, the third argument does not make any sense. The first argument is the *previously reduced value* and the second argument is the *next* value.

In your third example the third argument is optional, so it still works when it is passed only 2 arguments.

Comment: Read the documentation, so its the cumulative of two arguments to iterable reduces to final result. thanks